# PHP - using a loop with fwrite

Tags: php

I have a dynamic form that generates a xml file. The user can add add as many as they want. When the user clicks submit to generate the file, all entries should be written to the xml file.

Unfortunately right now, only the last entry is getting written. I know i need a loop statement but I've having issues.

Here's the form.php --> https://jsfiddle.net/jdarville/mbfjmd02/9/

And here's the save.php(i only included the important parts):

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){


$message0 = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';


foreach($_POST['howmany'] as $item_number){
  $item_number = $item_number;
}   

for($x=1;$x<=$item_number;$x++){
    //echo $_POST["templateid".$x]; 


$message2 = '<Template tid="'. $_POST["templateid".$x].'" gid="000">
   <OriginalKey>Queues/Scan</OriginalKey>
   <Params>
}


for($x=1;$x<=$item_number;$x++){
$message2 = '</FileFormatInformation>
   <StorePath>'. $_POST["uncpath".$x].'</StorePath>
   <UserName>'.$_POST["username".$x].'</UserName>
   <Password>'.$_POST["password".$x].'</Password>
</SMBStoreParameter>
<caption2>'.$_POST["scantoname".$x].'</caption2>
<userName />
}
}

$file = fopen("test.xml","w");
echo fwrite($file,"$message0 $message1 $message2 ");
fclose($file);
?>
```

Comment: No need to use foreach to get item count

Comment: Don't generate xml like this. if there are ANY xml metachars in the posted data, you'll generated broken xml and cause parse errors in whatever's receiving/using the xml. At bare minimum, at LEAST run the post data through `htmlspecialchars()`...

Comment: I know its not best practice but it is working...?

Comment: Is `$_POST['howmany']` really an array that you need to loop over? Why would you have multiple inputs containing the total number of inputs? And `$item_number = $item_number;` makes no sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like $message2 = needs to be $message2 .= (that's dot equals)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $message0    = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
    $item_number = intval($_POST['howmany']);
    for ($x = 1; $x <= $item_number; $x++)
    {
        $message1.= '<Template tid="' . $_POST["templateid" . $x] . '" gid="000">   <OriginalKey>Queues/Scan</OriginalKey>   <Params>';
    }
    for ($x = 1; $x <= $item_number; $x++)
    {
        $message2.= '</FileFormatInformation>   <StorePath>' . $_POST["uncpath" . $x] . '</StorePath>   <UserName>' . $_POST["username" . $x] . '</UserName>   <Password>' . $_POST["password" . $x] . '</Password></SMBStoreParameter><caption2>' . $_POST["scantoname" . $x] . '</caption2><userName />';
    }

    $file = fopen("test.xml", "w");
    echo fwrite($file, "$message0 $message1 $message2 ");
    fclose($file);
}
?>
```

Your xml is not valid because some tags have not been closed and some have not been opened below are some invalid xml tags.

`<Params>` has not been closed.

`</FileFormatInformation>` has not been opened.

Comment: Are you going to show how to fix his code to generate valid XML? If not, this isn't a very helpful answer, and should just be a comment.

Comment: But I dont know what kinf of structure he wants in XML

Comment: I didnt provide the entire xml code because its about 8 pages. I only added the parts with dynamic data. The XML file is getting generated with no problem. I am also able to import the XML file without any issues. The only issue is that its only keeping the last values entered on the form.

Comment: @JCD That's because the `for` loop reassigns `$message2` each time through the loop, instead of appending to it.